# How I can count how many suspended proceses there are in a shell script linux bash

Tags: linux, bash

I tried to  write a shell script that shows and counts how many suspended processes there are.

But I succeeded only to show the suspended processes with:

```
#!/bin/bash
list_ps=`ps aux | awk '$8~/T/'`
echo "$list_ps"
```

I tried to count the suspended processes with:

```
nr=0
for i in $list_ps
do
  nr=`expr $nr + 1`
done
```

Of course this didn't work because it counted every word there was even with the first row that had the USER PID STAT COMMAND.

Can you give me any suggestion on how I should do it?
Also here is the output for `"ps aux | awk '$8~/T/"` after I stopped some sleep processes.

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
alexsan+  6441  0.0  0.0   9008   736 pts/0    T    16:17   0:00 sleep 5000
alexsan+  6511  0.0  0.0   9008   820 pts/0    T    16:18   0:00 sleep 5000
alexsan+  7041  0.0  0.0   9008   760 pts/0    T    16:21   0:00 sleep 333
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please have a look at [how to format code blocks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) before asking a new question.

Comment: please provide us with output sample for `ps aux | awk '$8~/T/'`

Comment: I added the output.

Comment: @PaducelAlexandru does it work with you ?

Comment: Thanks it helped I wasn't sure how to use wc ! It works perfectly

Comment: People on stackoverflow are so kind, can't wait to help others when I know more!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

additional characters can be added to the state field (depending on the options you use), so this might be a safer approach:

```
ps aux | awk '$8~/T/'
```

to count how many processes you have with a header :

```
ps aux | awk '$8~/T/' | wc -l
```

to skip the header :

```
count=$(ps aux | awk '$8~/T/' | wc -l)
echo $((count -1))
```

one line version :

```
echo $(( $(ps aux | awk '$8~/T/' | wc -l)-1))
```

within single `awk` :

```
ps aux | awk 'NR>1 && $8~/T/' | wc -l
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the option `--no-header` of the `ps` command, you will not need to substract 1 from the number of lines of output you get from `wc -l`, so you just have to issue:

```
ps --no-header aux | awk '$8 ~ /T/' | wc -l
```

And since the header will contain the `'T'` of `'STAT'` in field #8, it was necessary to filter this line out.

Comment: you can neglect header with awk where `NR > 1`, `ps aux | awk '$8~/T/' | awk ' NR>1{print}' | wc -l`

Comment: @MahmoudOdeh: of course you can, but I don't see why I should let `ps` generate a header that `awk` will have to skip. Thank you anyway for suggesting.

Answer (score 2):

Within single `awk` could you please try following.

```
echo $(( $(ps aux | awk '$8~/T/{count++} END{print count-1}')))
```

Or to assign to a variable simply:

```
var=$(ps aux | awk '$8~/T/{count++} END{print count-1}')
```